# Why is my string changing in this pipeline?

Tags: atom

I was trying to pipe an output url into the `open` command but found several instances where despite changing the color settings of grep or piping further output through other utils like `awk` or `cut` I was still getting special chars in the output. As shown below:

[image]

The first 2 times I run the `open` command I get sent two these two urls respectively:

[image]
[image]

You can see the special chars being tacked onto the urls despite being piped through cut, or changing the color settings. This is confirmed with the `od` command:

```
➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | grep https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -atx1
0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
           1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
           75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
           6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a

 ➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | grep --color=none https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -atx1
 0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
            1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
 0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
            75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
 0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
            6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a
 0000052
```

The next two outputs try to use `awk` to strip off the url from `apm` however they also introduce special chars, and the `open` command then tries to open them as files. This is confirmed with `od`:

```
➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | awk -F' ' '/http/ {print $2}' | od -atx1
0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
           1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
           75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
           6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a
```

The solution has been to use a lovely [sed oneliner](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed), `sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"` that succeeds at stripping off all the special chars. The final `open` command uses this oneliner and succeeds at going to `https://github.com/atom/vim-mode` as expected. This is confirmed by `od`:

```
➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | awk -F' ' '/http/ {print $2}' | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | od -atx1
0000000    h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h   u   b   .   c
           68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68  75  62  2e  63
0000020    o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -   m   o   d   e
           6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d  6d  6f  64  65
0000040   nl
           0a
0000041
```

So this leaves some questions:

1. Why isn't the `grep --color=none` working?
2. Why are my various other utils tacking on special chars?

I suspect it has something to do with my shell settings. I'm using [zim](https://github.com/Eriner/zim) with the [gitster](https://github.com/shashankmehta/dotfiles/blob/master/thesetup/zsh/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/gitster.zsh-theme) theme

**edit**

setting `TERM=dumb` appears to have no affect:

```
➜  github-application master ✓ diff <(TERM=dumb apm show vim-mode | od -atx1) <(apm show vim-mode | od -atx1)
➜  github-application master ✓
```

setting `NPM_CONFIG_COLOR=false` also appears to have no affect:

```
➜  ~/w/s/g/m/todo master ✓ diff <(NPM_CONFIG_COLOR=false apm show vim-mode | od -atx1) <(apm show vim-mode | od -atx1)
➜  ~/w/s/g/m/todo master ✓
```

I think it's because of the underline in the url. I've been exploring it further in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336126/where-does-the-coffeescript-underline-method-come-from)

Comment: The obvious thing to blame is `open`.  As a guess, it is trying to provide an absolute path, and the prompt is hinting that you are running this command from your home directory. It would be interesting to see the results of running the same command from say /tmp.

Comment: What is the output of `type grep`, of `apm show vim-mode | grep https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -t x1`?

Comment: @Gilles please see edit

Comment: @Gilles: Next time you ask someone to pipe something into `od`, please specify `od -atx1`.

Comment: It's a fair bet that `apm` is the one outputing those characters. There's nothing `grep` or anybody else can do about it. Have you tried examining `apm`'s output directly?

Comment: @mbigras What happens if you run `TERM=dumb apm show vim-mode | grep.....`? Do you still get the `escape [ 2 4 m` (which turns off underlining in an ansi terminal) ?

Comment: @icarus see question edit

Comment: A web search suggests that apm is https://github.com/atom/apm and that it calls npm. A search for that suggests that it might respect `NPM_CONFIG_COLOR=false apm show vim-mode | grep.....`. If the sequences are always generated then we have to remove them with something like the sed oneliner. As comments on the linked web page say, the `[m|K]` should be `[mK]`.

Comment: I was with you until you started talking about `[m|K]`, what is that in this context?

Comment: In a regular expression you can have an `or` construction using the `|` character, so you can say `this|that` to match `this` or `that`. For single characters you can have character classes `[afg]` will match an `a`, an `f` or a `g`. Someone has gotten confused and said `[m|K]` meaning to match an `m` or a `K`, but it also matches an `|` character. So you should fix your `lovely sed oneliner` to change `[m|K]` to `[mK]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the special chars are being inserted by `apm`.

```
➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | grep https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -atx1
0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
           1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
           75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
           6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a

 ➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | grep --color=none https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -atx1
 0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
            1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
 0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
            75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
 0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
            6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a
 0000052

➜  ~  apm show vim-mode | od -atx1
0000000  esc   [   3   6   m   v   i   m   -   m   o   d   e esc   [   3
           1b  5b  33  36  6d  76  69  6d  2d  6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  33
0000020    9   m  nl   �  94  9c   �  94  80   �  94  80  sp esc   [   3
           39  6d  0a  e2  94  9c  e2  94  80  e2  94  80  20  1b  5b  33
0000040    3   m   0   .   6   5   .   1 esc   [   3   9   m  nl   �  94
           33  6d  30  2e  36  35  2e  31  1b  5b  33  39  6d  0a  e2  94
0000060   9c   �  94  80   �  94  80  sp esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p
           9c  e2  94  80  e2  94  80  20  1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70
0000100    s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h   u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a
           73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68  75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61
0000120    t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -   m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4
           74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d  6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34
0000140    m  nl   �  94  9c   �  94  80   �  94  80  sp   A   d   d  sp
           6d  0a  e2  94  9c  e2  94  80  e2  94  80  20  41  64  64  20
0000160    v   i   m  sp   m   o   d   a   l  sp   c   o   n   t   r   o
           76  69  6d  20  6d  6f  64  61  6c  20  63  6f  6e  74  72  6f
0000200    l  nl   �  94  9c   �  94  80   �  94  80  sp   5   0   3   8
           6c  0a  e2  94  9c  e2  94  80  e2  94  80  20  35  30  33  38
0000220    6   1  sp   d   o   w   n   l   o   a   d   s  nl   �  94  94
           36  31  20  64  6f  77  6e  6c  6f  61  64  73  0a  e2  94  94
0000240    �  94  80   �  94  80  sp   1   0   1   4  sp   s   t   a   r
           e2  94  80  e2  94  80  20  31  30  31  34  20  73  74  61  72
0000260    s  nl  nl   R   u   n  sp   `   a   p   m  sp   i   n   s   t
           73  0a  0a  52  75  6e  20  60  61  70  6d  20  69  6e  73  74
0000300    a   l   l  sp   v   i   m   -   m   o   d   e   `  sp   t   o
           61  6c  6c  20  76  69  6d  2d  6d  6f  64  65  60  20  74  6f
0000320   sp   i   n   s   t   a   l   l  sp   t   h   i   s  sp   p   a
           20  69  6e  73  74  61  6c  6c  20  74  68  69  73  20  70  61
0000340    c   k   a   g   e   .  nl  nl
           63  6b  61  67  65  2e  0a  0a
0000350
```

with `e esc   [   2   4` being the specific lines of interest.

This is confirmed by switching to bash and getting the same result:

```
bash-3.2# apm show vim-mode | grep https | cut -d' ' -f2 | od -atx1
0000000  esc   [   4   m   h   t   t   p   s   :   /   /   g   i   t   h
           1b  5b  34  6d  68  74  74  70  73  3a  2f  2f  67  69  74  68
0000020    u   b   .   c   o   m   /   a   t   o   m   /   v   i   m   -
           75  62  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  61  74  6f  6d  2f  76  69  6d  2d
0000040    m   o   d   e esc   [   2   4   m  nl
           6d  6f  64  65  1b  5b  32  34  6d  0a
```

Thanks @muru for the tip!

Comment: If you're getting colors in your grep output, fix this. Find the place in your configuration where `grep` is aliased (or otherwise wrapped around) to `grep --color=always` and replace it by `grep --color=auto`. Passing `--color=always` in your configuration will cause you this sort of trouble again and again. However, `sed`, `awk` and `cut` don't even have any option to add special characters, so your analysis may be wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to demonstrate with your screenshots? You seem to be demonstrating that, when `grep --color=auto` writes directly to the terminal (i.e., it is the last command in a pipeline, and doesn’t have output redirected), the output is in color, but when you pipe it into something (*anything*, including `cut`), the output is not in color. ***This is exactly Gilles’s point.*** If you can still reproduce your original error with `grep` confirmed to be aliased to `grep --color=auto` (piping into `cut`, but not `sed` or `awk`), let us know.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … And, if you can identify a clear case where `sed`, `awk` or `cut` adds inappropriate characters to its output, we’d be interested in seeing a demonstration of that, too.

Comment: I’m still confused about what’s happening. I still don’t find your screenshots particularly illuminating or convincing.  There’s something going on that you’re not telling us (and I’m assuming that it’s because you don’t understand it, and not that you’re deliberately withholding critical information) — for example, [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOVpw.png) shows the output of `cut` *not* underlined, but the output of `echo` ***is** underlined* — one time out of three!  That doesn’t make any sense. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But, to get back to the point: if you’re finding that the `awk -F' ' '{print $2}'` command does what you need (i.e., the same as `cut -d' ' -f2`), then eliminate the `grep` and just do `apm show vim-mode | awk -F' ' '/http/ {print $2}'`. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. Try leaving out the `-F' '` — what happens then?

Comment: @G-Man I've updated the original question